# Allowing Empty Cells in a datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am currently using a datagrid where I leave the value empty for a few weeks until I need to fill it. My datagrid will not allow the value to be empty and shows a red box. How can I allow a null value in this column?

I have tried to remove all row validation with `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"` in xaml but that hasn't changed anything either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that cell is displaying a value of type `DateTime`, which is a non-nullable type. Therefore you have to have a value for it.

You could either use a `string` property to display the scrap date, or make the `DateTime` nullable using `DateTime? dateTime = null;`